# Правильно-ли реализована агрегация?

Tags: java

```
public class Sim {
    private String operator;

    public  Sim(String opera){
        setOperator(opera);
    }

    public String getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }

    public void setOperator(String opera) {
        operator = opera;
    }
    public void Print(){
        System.out.println("Название оператора:"+getOperator());
    }
}

public class Battery {
    private int power;

    public  Battery(int pow) {
        setPower(pow);
    }

    public int getPower() {
        return power;
    }

    public void setPower(int pow) {
        power = pow;
    }
    public void Print(){
        System.out.println("Мощность батареи:"+getPower());
    }
}

public class Smartphone {
    private Sim smartphoneSim;
    private Battery smartphoneBattery;
    private String model;

    public void Smartphone(Sim s1, Battery b1) {
        setSmartphone(b1);
        setSmartphone(s1);
    }

    public void setSmartphone(Sim s1) {
        smartphoneSim = s1;
    }

    public void setSmartphone(Battery b1) {
        smartphoneBattery = b1;
    }

    public Sim getSmartphone() {
        return smartphoneSim;

    }

    public Battery getSmartphoneBattery() {
        return smartphoneBattery;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Battery b1 = new Battery(1000);
        Sim s1 = new Sim("МТС");
        b1.Print();
        s1.Print();
    }
}
```

Правильно-ли я создал агрегацию? В методе main я передаю значения как class `Sim`, так class `Battery` и вызываю метод `print`. А могу ли я так передать их, но через class `Smartphone` и так же вывести все это?

---

```
        public class Smartphone {
        private Sim smartphoneSim;
        private Battery smartphoneBattery;
        private String model;


        public Smartphone(String model){
            this.model=model;
        }

        public String getModel() {
            return model;
        }

        public void setModel(String model) {
            this.model = model;
        }

        public Smartphone(String operator, int power ){
            smartphoneSim = new Sim(operator);
            smartphoneSim.setOperator(operator);
            smartphoneBattery = new Battery(power);
            smartphoneBattery.setPower(power);
        }
        public void printl(){
            System.out.println("Модель : " + getModel());
    //        smartphoneSim.Print();
    //        smartphoneBattery.Print();
        }
    }
    public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Battery battery = new Battery(1500);
        Smartphone smartphone = new Smartphone("Samsung");
        smartphone.printl();
        Sim sim = new Sim("Beeline");
        sim.print();
        battery.print();

    }
}
```

> в class Smartphone не получается вызвать метод print class Sim,аналогично с методом print class Buttery.Вызвал его отдельно через class TestClass.Работает.Но как-то некрасиво.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так реализуйте метод `print` у `Smartphone` и в нем вызовите `print` для и `Sim` `Battery`

```
public class Smartphone {
    private Sim smartphoneSim;
    private Battery smartphoneBattery;
    private String model;
    ..........
    public void print() {
      System.out.println("Модель: " + model);
      smartphoneSim.print();
      smartphoneBattery.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Battery battery = new Battery(1500);
        Smartphone smartphone = new Smartphone("Samsung");
        smartphone.print();
        Sim smartphone1 = new Sim("Beeline");

    }
}

Comment: Модель : Samsung
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Smartphone.print(Smartphone.java:27)
 at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:6)

Comment: @ЭдуардФархутдинов Обманываете. В Вашем коде нет конструктора `Smartphone` куда можно передать только строку. В любом случае, если у Вас поля `smartphoneSim` или `smartphoneBattery` могут быть неинициализированы, то нужно проверять их на `null` перед обращением к ним

Comment: @ Anton Shchyrov я снизу исправил.Добавил конструктор.То есть мне перед обращением к методу print нужно проверить их на null?

Comment: @ЭдуардФархутдинов Конечно. А как иначе?